# how to change the value of a color in a qlist

Tags: c++, qt, qlist

I had an object of a Circle, it contains the properties to draw it like width, coor xy, color. I had a qlist of this circles(objects) but when i try to change the color i get an error.

```
class Circle {
 int x;
 int y;
 int width;
 QColor color
}

QList <Circle> circles;
```

I add some circles to the list here is the problem

```
circles.at(3).color = Qt::yellow;
```

passing ‘const QColor’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘QColor& QColor::operator=(Qt::GlobalColor)’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `at()` function of a `QList` returns a const reference: `const T & QList::at(int i) const`, so you can not modify it. Use `operator[]` instead: `circles[3].color = Qt::yellow`

Also note that right now all members of your class are `private` (by default), so you will not be able to set `color` anyway.

Comment: Do not forget to check the index is out of range before using `[]` operator.

Comment: @vahancho, `at()` doesn't check for array range either, so I assume the OP knows about it.